# Service bus queue trigger with Azure function calling multiple times for same message

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I am having two azure function one is http function and another one is queue trigger function. In http function i am adding a messasge to queue and in queue trigger processing it. When i log the message in queue trigger sometimes its triggering multiple times with the same message ? What will be the reason ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

There might be several reasons. Without looking at the code, my guesses would be the following:

- HTTP based function is invoked more than once. Can be verified by assigning either a unique message ID derived from the message properties and then de-duplicating using ASB's native de-dup.
- Queue based function is not completing messages in time (lock duration time) and it becomes available again.

A few resources on message de-duplication you might find useful:

- [Deduplicating ASB messages with Functions](http://microsoftintegration.guru/2016/09/20/use-azure-function-to-deduplicate-messages-on-azure-service-bus/)
- [Creating custom message ID to deduplicate messages](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/bend-message-deduplication-on-azure-service-bus-to-your-will)

Comment: Its due to the second. I made lock time as 5 min and i think azure function will automatically resetlock time even if its more than 5 mins

Comment: Azure functions used under consumption plan cannot run longer than 5 mins  Also, max lock duration ootb is 5 mins. Beyond that lock needs to be renewed or design needs to be changed.