# Azure service bus receiver message handler get invoked with same message multiple times

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using Azure Service Bus JS sdk to receive messages from a ASB topic.
The receiver is using the default mode (i.e. the Peek) mode. And I call completeMessage() in my message handler.  What I am seeing is, the message handler is being called multiple times with the same message. And the sender only sends the message once.

```
const myMessageHandler = async (messageReceived) => {
      this.receiver.completeMessage(messageReceived);
     // process messageReceived
     .....
} 
this.receiver.subscribe({
    processMessage: myMessageHandler,
    processError: myErrorHandler
});
```

Can you please tell me what can be the issue? I think ASB is delivery the message multiple times despite the receives already complete the message.

Comment: You can refer to [Service bus queue trigger with Azure function calling multiple times for same message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44051584), [Azure Service Bus: Duplicate messages are processing in message queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54949533) and [ServiceBusTrigger triggers multiple times the same message](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2796). You can also open an issue on GitHub: [azure-sdk-for-js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, in Azure Service Bus a messages will be re-processed if no action was done to that message by the receiving party. And that action can be completing, deferring, dead-lettering.

But this should not the issue in your case as your are using the `completeMessage()` action to the message you are receiving. So, the problem you are facing could be due to an **exception**. As a general best practice, it’s a good idea to handle all exceptions in the message processing code so the lock duration is never reached as shown in the code snippet below.

```
    ...
    try { 
            //Process message code 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
            //Abandon message
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Check what exception you are getting. One I can thing of is `MessageLockLostException`, it due to the default value of autoComplete. **Note that the default value of [AutoComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.onmessageoptions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet#properties) is true. Then if we are going to use `completeMessage()` action then we should set `autoComplete` as false. Or else it can result to `MessageLockLostException`.**

If you are still facing the problem check this [Config options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127001/the-lock-supplied-is-invalid-either-the-lock-expired-or-the-message-has-alread#:%7E:text=ServiceBus%20Queue%20or,set%20it%20to%201) suggested by @Tomas. Also check the [Best Practices for performance improvements using Service Bus Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2) document for more information.